# undefined references to `strerror_s' while building lua-openssl on alpine image

Tags: c, lua, openssl, undefined, alpine-linux

I am trying to build an openresty alpine image with lua-openssl like so

```
FROM openresty/openresty:alpine-fat

# Set the version
ENV RESTY_CONFIG_OPTIONS_MORE "--with-ngx_http_ssl_module"
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

RUN ls /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs

COPY lualib /usr/local/openresty/nginx/lualib
RUN chown -R nobody:root /usr/local/openresty/nginx/lualib

RUN apk add --update \
    openssl openssl-dev \
    lua5.3 luajit-dev  lua-socket   \
    git

RUN git clone https://github.com/zhaozg/lua-openssl.git /usr/local/lua-openssl;     \
    cd /usr/local/lua-openssl;  \
    git checkout e923252b28cff43add6382853cc85ed888c4474b;   \
    make
```

But I get the one below and a lot of such errors:

> /usr/local/lua-openssl/deps/lua-compat/c-api/compat-5.3.c:74:
>   undefined reference to `strerror_s' ./libopenssl.a(cms.o): In function`
>   compat53_strerror':
>   /usr/local/lua-openssl/deps/lua-compat/c-api/compat-5.3.c:74:
>   undefined reference to `strerror_s'
>   ./libopenssl.a(compat.o):/usr/local/lua-openssl/deps/lua-compat/c-api/compat-5.3.c:74:
>   more undefined references to`strerror_s' follow collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make: *** [Makefile:94: openssl.so] Error 1

Am I missing a package?

Comment: The `strerror_s()` function is an optional feature in [C11 Annex K.3.7.4.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.4.2).  It is implemented by Microsoft, but not usually by other vendors or suppliers.  Are you running on a Unix-like platform or on Windows?

Comment: `COMPAT53_HAVE_STRERROR_S` is enabled only when you have a C11 compatible compiler or running if it's `cl.exe` doing the compile. Maybe your build is switching gcc/clang compiler or compiler versions midway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using Mingw64 on Windows 7

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer how do I prevent it from switching compilers. Is there an environment variable that could do that?

Comment: I'm insufficiently familiar with Lua and Lua-OpenSSL, especially in a Windows and MInGW64 environment, to be able to give direct help.  However, it is probable that something (Lua-OpenSSL) is configured to use a different library than the rest (do all the other symbols causing trouble also end `_s`?).  The `_s` extension is notable because those functions are defined by Microsoft in their CRT (C run time).  It isn't clear to me if the rest of the code is using the CRT, or whether there's another problem.

Comment: Yes the other symbols causing trouble also end in _s. I'll try asking someone with a mac build my docker image and let me know

Comment: @PeggyScott I'll try building it on my Windows VBox and let you know how it works. Also, your error message seems like it's from Linux?

Comment: @PeggyScott You may have to compile OpenSSL, Lua 5.1 on windows using MSVC and then compile lua-openssl with the same compiler. This seems to work on mine. Any other combination doesn't.

Comment: There was a [bug fix regarding C11 Annex K feature test macros](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3/commit/daebe77a2f498817713df37f0bb316db1d82222f) which ended up in lua-openssl just a few hours ago. Updating the lua-openssl commit you are using could potentially fix the problem.

Comment: Wow let me try that :) Thanks a ton Unmanned Player and siffiejoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) We grabbed the trusty image instead of alpine-fat. 
(2) Overrode the make file with one that uses lcrypto lib to build.

And that is the only setting I know to make this work.

I did not try compiling with MSVC++.

My issue and it's fix is tracked in https://github.com/zhaozg/lua-openssl/issues/138